# Compiling Wifi driver for Linux: Void value not ignored as it ought to be

Tags: c, gcc

I am compiling a driver for a USB wifi for my machine. The code is very buggy (thanks TP-Link!) and I've had to make many corrections/modifications to the code - I am now at the last error, which has me stumped.

The following line in the code is causing the problem:

`#define _seqdump seq_printf`

I can't find the prototype for seq_printf, but from the error message, it seems to be a void func. However, when I read through the code, I see that the return value from the function is being used in branching statements ... ?! :/

How do I solve this so I can compile the library? Any flags I can pass to the compile to not treat this as an error?

Or should I write a wrapper (to return what?!) around seq_printf?

Comment: Link to your git repo? For `seq_printf()`, see [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/seq_file.c#n410).

Comment: maybe you could post some examples of the branches where the return code of the function is used

Answer (score 0):

What version of the Kernel do you have?

Personally I stumbled upon the same error message while compiling for my raspberry pi and the reason was that for the version of Kernel that I had (4.14.52-v7+), the code I was trying to compile was already outdated.

As described here: https://github.com/paralin/rtl8821au/issues/6

I just went ahead and cloned this repository: https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU, which seems to have an updated version of the driver.

I was able to compile after that.